# Minkowski's Bound and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{4}{\pi})^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: limits, algebraic-number-theory

Recently, I have been studying about Minkowski's bound in Algebraic Number Theory and this post will consist of two questions on this topic.

*Question 1*: Is there a rigorous way of calculating the following limit, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{4}{\pi})^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ (take as $n$ goes through $\mathbb{N}$.)?

This is inspired by Minkowski's bound. Intuitively, I am aware that this limit will approach to $0$ (and Desmos has indeed confirmed my intuition) since $n^n$ grows much much faster than other two terms. However, is there a way to formalise this?

*Question 2:* Can there be a case where the [Minkowski's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound)  be less than $1$?

I am fairly sure that the answer is no. If it is then any ideal is equivalent to an ideal with norm $0$, however this just does not make sense since the norm of an ideal is, after all, just the cardinality of a group?

Many thanks in advance for helping either question!

Comment: I don't know anything about Minkowski's bound, but it's simple to do question $1$ with Stirling's approximation.

Comment: With Stirling approximation the limit boils down to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt {2\pi n}(\frac4 {\pi e^2})^{\frac n2} $, which is pretty obvious.

Comment: For the second question, the Minkowski bound $M$ cannot be less than one, by definition: it means that there is an integral ideal $I$ with norm at most $M$: then as $N(I) \geq 1$, $M \geq 1$.

Comment: If the sequence under limit is denoted by $a_n$ then $a_{n+1}/a_n\to \frac{2}{e\sqrt{\pi}}<1$ and hence original sequence tends to $0$.